# Is it possible to run single .erb file without rails in apache?

Tags: ruby, apache, passenger

I got a ubuntu machine and im tryying to create a simple view with ruby.Im well familiar with rails but i wanted to a simple standalone(if possible) like a php one with ruby.I got apache2 installed on my machine.I also got nginx and passenger.

The file i want to create is a simple 3+2= <%= 3+2 %>.Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

Look into using sinatra for simpler implementations. It runs as a webserver as well but is much more lightweight than rails, and has erb support. Remember, erb is a library and not a native ruby feature, so you need a way to compile the view to include the ruby variables.

Its also possible to write your own webserver logic using Rack, and hook into erb to render the view, but thats probably more work than you want to do. With sinatra, rendering an erb is as simple as:

```
require 'sinatra'

get '/' do
  erb :index
end
```

(If you had a file in a views/ directory named index.erb)

Answer (score 0):

Ruby comes with the `erb` executable.

You can compile the file to HTML with the following shell command

```
erb input.html.erb > output.html
```